# Does the name of the xsl:template effects the result of function fn:key，and why？ thanks a lot

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

I find a appearance , that I can't get a correct result with fn:key function in a template which has a name attribute. When I just delete the name attribute of xsl:template, the result are right. That amazes me. 
Would somebody like to tell the reason? thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
xmlns:rel="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"

xmlns:map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs w rel r map"
version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="key_styles_id" match="w:style" use="@w:styleId"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="styles" select="doc(resolve-uri('styles.xml',    document-uri(/)))" as="document-node()?"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:document/w:body/w:p">
        <xsl:with-param name="styles" tunnel="yes" select="$styles"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="all_paragraph" match="w:p">
    <xsl:param name="styles" tunnel="yes" required="yes" />

    <xsl:value-of select="$styles"/>

    <xsl:variable name="style_id" select="w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:variable name="style_node" select="key('key_styles_id', $style_id, $styles)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$style_node"/>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The input xml is the documment.xml in directory of a unzip docx, the docx file can be replaced to a file that have some words with styles.

The problem is that:
If I delete the name attribute whose value is 'all_paragraph', the key function will get the right result and $style_node has many elements data. if not , the key function return empty and $style_node has nothing.

The xslt processor that I use is saxon-he 9.8.0.12

input source: document.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
    xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
    xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"
    xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing"
    xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:b/>
                    <w:b/>
                    <w:bCs/>
                    <w:color w:val="C9211E"/>
                </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:b/>
                    <w:bCs/>
                    <w:color w:val="C9211E"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">12345good day. </w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:i/>
                    <w:i/>
                    <w:iCs/>
                    <w:color w:val="77BC65"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
                    <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
                </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:i/>
                    <w:iCs/>
                    <w:color w:val="77BC65"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="28"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
                    <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>64789hello world</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr>
            <w:type w:val="nextPage"/>
            <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
            <w:pgMar w:left="1134" w:right="1134" w:header="0" w:top="1134" w:footer="0"
                w:bottom="1134" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:pgNumType w:fmt="decimal"/>
            <w:formProt w:val="false"/>
            <w:textDirection w:val="lrTb"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

styles.xml which used in xslt code like `doc('styles.xml')`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:styles xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="w14">
    <w:docDefaults>
        <w:rPrDefault>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Liberation Serif" w:hAnsi="Liberation Serif" w:eastAsia="新宋体"
                    w:cs="Lucida Sans"/>
                <w:kern w:val="2"/>
                <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="zh-CN" w:bidi="hi-IN"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:rPrDefault>
        <w:pPrDefault>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:widowControl/>
            </w:pPr>
        </w:pPrDefault>
    </w:docDefaults>
    <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Normal">
        <w:name w:val="Normal"/>
        <w:qFormat/>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:widowControl/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Liberation Serif" w:hAnsi="Liberation Serif" w:eastAsia="新宋体"
                w:cs="Lucida Sans"/>
            <w:color w:val="auto"/>
            <w:kern w:val="2"/>
            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            <w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="zh-CN" w:bidi="hi-IN"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:style>
    <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Style14">
        <w:name w:val="标题样式"/>
        <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
        <w:next w:val="Style15"/>
        <w:qFormat/>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:keepNext w:val="true"/>
            <w:spacing w:before="240" w:after="120"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Liberation Sans" w:hAnsi="Liberation Sans" w:eastAsia="微软雅黑"
                w:cs="Lucida Sans"/>
            <w:sz w:val="28"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:style>
    <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Style15">
        <w:name w:val="Body Text"/>
        <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="276" w:before="0" w:after="140"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:rPr/>
    </w:style>
    <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Style16">
        <w:name w:val="List"/>
        <w:basedOn w:val="Style15"/>
        <w:pPr/>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Lucida Sans"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:style>
    <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Style17">
        <w:name w:val="Caption"/>
        <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
        <w:qFormat/>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:suppressLineNumbers/>
            <w:spacing w:before="120" w:after="120"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Lucida Sans"/>
            <w:i/>
            <w:iCs/>
            <w:sz w:val="24"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:style>
    <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Style18">
        <w:name w:val="索引"/>
        <w:basedOn w:val="Normal"/>
        <w:qFormat/>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:suppressLineNumbers/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Lucida Sans"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:style>
</w:styles>
```

my screenshots:

[first result with name attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuUi0.png)

[2nd result without name attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqBT2.png)

Comment: Consider to show minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT and output you get versus the one you want to allow us to reproduce the problem. It is not clear how you use the `key` function and how you use the template, a named template, if the name is used, is called by `xsl:call-template`, without a name, it is used if an `xsl:apply-templates` processes a node that matches the `match` pattern.

Comment: @MartinHonnen， hi, I have post my code, and more illustrate about my question. thanks.

Comment: I don't see why deleting or maintaining a `name` attribute on an `xsl:template` should change the behaviour of code that relies on `xsl:apply-templates`. If you can add minimal but complete samples of the two input document that show the failure so that others can reproduce it we might be able to tell more.

Comment: The problem is just depended on the name attribute which  I probably need not use.

Comment: @MartinHonnen , the input documents are easy to generate, create a .docx file, append some word in it ,  then change  them   cololr or font size, font style, that will make the docx file has style data.  Then,  rename the docx file to a zip file ,and upzip it , the document.xml and sytles.xml will apear in a "word" folder  in unziped path. I don't kown how to upload a file.

Comment: It is not my task to try to make up samples to reproduce your problem, please add minimal samples as code snippets to your question, then we can take it from there.

Comment: No , it's mine, cause I think is easy to generate by mistake. I post the input source  file data. @MartinHonnen

Comment: Which output do you want to produce with `<xsl:value-of select="$style_node"/>`, given that that instruction would create a text node with the string value(s) of the selected node(s) and given that your elements only carry data in attributes? For what it is worth, I have replaced value-of with copy-of, but in a quick test I don't get any difference between the XSLT with or without the `name` attribute on the template, both return two `w:style` elements.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have post my screenshorts of the different results. please watch them.

Comment: which xslt processor do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I can't debug screenshots, ask the oXygen guys in their support forums if they have an explanation. I tested online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCSu/2 and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCSu/3, that tool uses Saxon 9.8.0.15 HE, and for testing there I inlined the second document.

Comment: the code `<xsl:value-of select="$styles"/>` and `<xsl:value-of select="$style_node"/>` just for debug, they doen't matter.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Ok , thank you a lot.

Comment: Excuse me, how to setting two input xml in the xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net ?@MartinHonnen

Comment: In the examples I have linked to the secondary input document is inlined. You could also load it with the `doc` function, but from a HTTP(S) server e.g. `doc('http://example.com/styles.xml')` if needed, local/relative URIS won't work.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Thank you again, you're so kind.