# what does 'pop' means in a xslt example on w3.org

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

the code is a example in second from last："Example: Output Hierarchic Section Numbers",
 https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#accumulator-examples

```
<xsl:accumulator name="section-nr" as="xs:integer*" 
             initial-value="0">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="section" phase="start" 
             select="0, head($value)+1, tail($value)"/>
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="section" phase="end" 
             select="tail($value) (:pop:)"/>
</xsl:accumulator>


<xsl:template match="section">
  <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="reverse(tail(accumulator-before('section-nr')))" 
              separator="."/>
  </p>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

What does the word ":pop:" in the second "xsl:accumulator-rule" means, Is it a key word or something defined ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an XPath comment which is a string that is delimited by the symbols `(:` and `:)`

Have a look at "5.5.2 Syntax of Patterns" of the link you provided:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#pattern-syntax

Comment: Would you like to watch my another question， please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59151172/does-the-name-of-the-xsltemplate-effects-the-result-of-function-fnkey-and-why

Comment: Since I believe you are new on SO it is customary to mark the answer as "accepted" if it answers your question. I will take a look at your other questions.

Comment: Yeah. your are right , I find the acception button right now. It's a check mark that not too easy to found.